# Как сохранить данные в файл по 3 символа?

Tags: c++

Знаю что через fstream можно это легко сделать, но меня интересует максимально быстрый способ

Например если данных больше 1-2 ГБ, мне надо быстро сохранять их в файл.

Comment: Порциями по 3 символа, скорее всего, в любом случае будет долго. Какова реальная задача?

Comment: тогда нужно идти по классике - сделать буффер (думаю, 4-8 кб для первой попытки будет достаточно. Как только он заполнился - записывать его на диск. Также не забыть корректно обработать хвосты.

Comment: Чтобы быстро сохранять в файл нужно уменьшить количество обращений к диску (так как в основном из за скорости диска замедляется файловый ввод-вывод). Следовательно лучше записывать данные не по 3 байта (тогда на 2гб файл приходится примерно *715 827 883* обращений к диску), а по 64кб (тогда кол-во обращений снизиться до *32 768*) или вообще по 1мб (всего *2048* запросов к диску).

Comment: очень спорно, что при буфере в 1мб будет 2048 обращений к диску.  Скорее всего их будет немного больше